# Foreach subcategory get products list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[category 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOzLX.png)

[category 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbb5K.png)

```
<ul class="row-list">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

        if (item.SubCategoryIsHome == true)
        {

            if (selectedSubCategory != null)
            {

                if (item.Name == string.Intern(selectedSubCategory.ToString()))
                {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("SubList", "Home", new { id = item.Id })">@item.Name</a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("SubList", "Home", new { id = item.Id })">@item.Name</a></li>
                }
            }
            else
            {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SubList", "Home", new { id = item.Id })">@item.Name</a></li>
            }
    }
}
```

Thats my problem. Iphone X looks in samsung and iphone category. i just want you to see it in the iphone category. Sorry for bad english, i hope you understand. Thank you.

Comment: if and else condition has the same code.

Comment: Can you give an example ?